# Uiwebview shouldloadrequest not getting called sometimes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using nine webviews inside a scrollview to get an infinte scrolling effect. I am loading image map inside each webviews. Now the problem is webviews are not responding sometimes for the touches, when it is a hard-touch(touch and hold). I am getting this issue when more than one webviews are visible. I have set the delegate for every webviews, I dont know why this happening.

I am loosing the selection while holding it, its grey color dissappears. This issue I am getting only in 3.2iPad device.

I need to get the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method called while each press. what i need to do?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the Apple document for UIWebview, they are clearly saying,"Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled."

check this link:- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

But I also do adding UIWebview to UIScrollview, But in my case the frame of a webview is same as the frame of scrollview. In this case the touchevent is properly detected.

And One issue I found in this case we can get UITapGestureRecognizer from that Uiwebviews...